# Default units in LaTeX

Tags: units

Which length will LaTeX apply, for example in

`\node[xshift=240,yshift=100]{…}`,

if the unit (as `xshift=1ex, 1em, 1in, 1pt, 1bp, 1dd, 1pc`, etc.)
is not specified explicitly?

And does this unit apply allover throughout the document?

Comment: That's package dependent. For Ti*k*Z the answer is `pt` in those options, and `cm` in coordinates (the latter can be configured by setting other values for `x` and `y`).

Comment: under the hood TeX requires presence of a unit in a numerical dimension assignment; so interface without unit is necessarily built on top of that and obeys choices done by interface author.